# Should i always use viewmodescope when network request?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

It is said that 'The ViewModel/Presenter layer should create coroutines' in https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad

Then i can only use livedata to notify result to Activity/Framgent.
I wonder if a simple request that only return success/failed such as register, add, or submit,  must i still use livedata in Activity
vm.request().observe(this, Observe{
    success->
    failed->
})
or i can create coroutine in Activity by lifeCycleScope without Callback
launch{
val ret = vm.request()
  if(ret.isSuccess){
   }
}

Comment: It depends on what you need. No one is forcing you to use LiveData. Here is some documentation about LiveData: [The advantages of using LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata). You can decide on your own if LiveData is usefull for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using the Live Data and ViewModel is to architect the code and to write the testable(to write unit test case) code. As Per the MVMM pattern, we should not have any business logic in the view. so we have moved the logic into the ViewModel. ViewModel should send the info to view so we are using the LiveData.

Reason for using the viewModelScope, we are doing the Long-running operation(API Call which takes 5secs to fetch the data from the server) we have called. At that time user clicks the back button goes off. we need to cancel the API call manually. (if we do not cancel which may cause the `Memory leak` problem)
if we use `viewModelScope` will take off the cancellation part.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  // call api 
  // update the LiveData
}
```

Without using the `viewModelScope` also we can do this operation using `GlobalScope` long-running process with happens till the app is live (Not the Prefered one https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc).